# I have a Timeline with a function for my slide, but it is still Frame-Dependent

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I try to make a slide using a timeline but it always results in something frame-dependent. If I slide with 60 frames/s, I go way less far than with 300FPS. Here is my timeline and blueprint, please help :/

[Timeline + Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBiAG.png)

[Inside the timeline. There is a function so it should be time-dependent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP7m9.png)

[Inside the function. I already try to disconnect almost everything, except the “Set Velocity”; it is still frame-dependent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRNhn.png)

I tried to disconnect EVERYTHING except the Set Velocity, with a fix value [1000, 0, 0] and even like this, it applies my velocity in relation with framerate. So I don't think that calculations made in the function are the problem.

Comment: I found a solution: use Add Movement Input instead of velocity :)

Comment: Nice one. You might encounter this issue in other places as well so I wanted to mention that you can account for it using the `Delta Seconds` output from the `Event Tick` event node. In the case in your question, you would set the velocity every tick using a bit of basic arithmetic (I have seen examples on the internet but I'm too lazy to find one for you!).